Help in understanding paracompactness
I have a great troubles in understanding the definition of paracompactness. I tried to make up some examples to better understand the definition. There is a theorem that says that every topological manifold $M$ is paracompact. $\mathbb{R}$ is an example of a manifold and we can cover $\mathbb{R}$ with open intervals of the form $(-n,\frac{1}{n})$ and $(-\frac{1}{n},n)$, given that cover I am unable to find a neighborhood of $0$ that would intersect only finitely many sets of any refinement. What am I missing?

From your comment below, it seems like you have a misunderstanding about what "refinement" means. A refinement is neither necessarily a subcover nor a supercover. There is, for example, a refinement of your cover that contains the set $(10, 11)$ but not the set $(-\frac 1{11}, 11)$. If you don't see why, have another look at the definition.

You have made a quantifier error.
The definition of paracompactness does not say "for any refinement", it instead says "there exists a refinement":

$M$ is paracompact if and only only if for any open cover $\mathcal U$ there exists an open refinement $\mathcal V$ of $\mathcal U$ such that for any point $p \in M$ there exists a neighborhood $A$ of $p$ that intersects only finitely many elements of $\mathcal V$.

So, are you able to find a refinement of the given open cover, and a neighborhood of $0$ which intersects only finitely many sets of that refinement?

What I had in mind is that I tried to find a small neighborhood that would match some refining, which seemed a bit easier and work from there. Regarding your question I don't know how to find a suitable neighborhood. What I keep thinking about is that infinately many sets intersect at $0$ wouldnt adding more sets(refinements) and taking a bigger set (neighborhood of $0$) make it worse?

@Addy137, a refinement of a cover is not necessarily a superset of the original cover. For instance, every subcover of an open cover is also a refinement.

You are certainly allowed to construct a refinement by adding new sets (and removing old sets). Each set you add must be open and it must be a subset of one of the sets in the original open cover. For example, you can add the new set $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ you would have a refinement because that set is contained in one of the original sets of the given open cover, namely $(-\frac{1}{2},2)$.

Yes indeed. In that case I can choose refinement to be a family of $(n,n+2)$ for $n \neq -1$ and $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$, and take the last set to be desired neighborhood of $0$ am I right?

That looks correct.

Thank you all for help. I have no more doubts.
